# Problems with MPI_Reduce

Tags: c++, mpi

First of all, very new to MPI. I have a program that uses the rectangle/midpoint rule to calculate the area of a function that is equal to pi. When I use a method involving sends and receives the calculation always gives a good value for pi. However, when testing MPI_Reduce to achieve the same thing I get pi for one processor, but using different numbers of processors I get a value less than pi. I have the code output the local_sum for each processor and then the global_sum from MPI_Reduce. The local sums add up to the global sum, which isn't pi. I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the section of code which is relevant:

```
/* Add up the areas calculated by each process */
if (my_rank == 0) {
    total = my_area;
    for (source = 1; source < p; source++) {
        MPI_Recv(&my_area, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        total = total + my_area;
    }
} else {  
    MPI_Send(&my_area, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest,
        tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

//*********TEST BEGIN FOR USING MPI_REDUCE*********
// Print the local sums on each process
printf("Local sum for process %d - %f\n",
   my_rank, my_area);

double global_sum;

// Reduce all of the local sums into the global sum
MPI_Reduce(
&my_area,        // send data
&global_sum,     // receive data
1,               // number of elements in send buffer
MPI_DOUBLE,      // MPI Datatype
MPI_SUM,         // MPI Reduce Operation
0,               // root process 
MPI_COMM_WORLD); // MPI Communicator
//**********TEST END FOR USING MPI_REDUCE**********

/* Print the result */
if (my_rank == 0) {
    printf("With n = %d rectangles, our estimate\n",
        n);
    printf("of the area from %f to %f = %.15f\n",
        a, b, total);
    cout << "The area calculated using MPI_Reduce was " << global_sum << "." << endl;
}
```

**The output of the code for a single processor is:**

Enter limits of integration a, b, and number of bins n, separated by spaces

0.0 1.0 10000000

Local sum for process 0 - 3.141593

With n = 10000000 rectangles, our estimate

of the area from 0.000000 to 1.000000 = 3.141592653473855

The area calculated using MPI_Reduce was 3.14159.

**The output of the code using (for example) four processors is:**

Local sum for process 1 - 0.923739

Local sum for process 2 - 0.775058

Local sum for process 0 - 0.453312

Local sum for process 3 - 0.453312

With n = 10000000 rectangles, our estimate

of the area from 0.000000 to 1.000000 = 3.141591655190580

The area calculated using MPI_Reduce was 2.60542.

Comment: Sum of local sums equals to `MPI_Reduce` result. Suppose that problem is not there.

Comment: Ah, you have corrupted main process's `my_area` variable on first loop. Use another variable to receive result there.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks very much!